# Encode value of string only if it is not UTF-8 in Java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I have a string `s` that receives a value from a database. Depending on which server is the database, the value comes in `UTF-8` encoding or not and I can't control that.

My problem is that I need to find a way to only encode the value of the string `s` with `URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8")` when that value is not `UTF-8`, otherwise it gives me some unwanted characters.

I can't use `juniversalchardet` to detect the encoding of the value.
How should I approach that to make sure I only encode when needed and get the correct value of the string?

Comment: `URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8") when that value is not UTF-8`? is not or is?

Comment: If you're retrieving the value as a `String`, it's already stored internally in memory as `UTF-16`. Your explanation is wrong, and you're going for the wrong solution. You're probably getting a corrupted value from the database already.

Comment: @ByeBye is not.

Comment: @Kayaman I know that, but the value inside the string can contain something like this: `like%20this`.

Comment: Repost of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622226/check-if-a-string-is-valid-utf-8-encoded-in-java

Comment: Sure, but that has nothing to do with character encoding. If spaces are converted to `%20` it means the string is URL encoded.

Comment: @Kayaman Right. So how can I convert strings that have `%20` to normal ones and also guarantee that strings that do not have `%20` are not affected?

Comment: No guarantees, but if you have URL encoded Strings, you need to [URLDecode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) them.

Comment: @joaopaulo.ps93 You **must** know a priori the form in which a string is encoded. If they hide that detail to you, that interface is not well defined.

Comment: Why is a database returning url-encoded strings?  Are they stored as url-encoded in the record fields? If so, then you don't really need to re-encode them with `URLEncoder`, just use them as-is. Unless the original source did not use UTF-8 when encoding Unicode characters to byte octets when url-encoding, and you want to re-encode the url-encoding using UTF-8 octets. In which case, use `URLDecoder` to decode the url-encoding to a `String` using the original charset (if you don't know that, you are SOL), then use `URLEncoder` to url-encode that `String` using UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you for your help! You were right, I was using `URLEncoder` when I should use `URLDecoder`. @Kayaman, can you kindly post your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @joaopaulo.ps93 No problem. There you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `Strings` containing `%20` (or in general %dd, where dd is a hex value `00-FF`) it's [URL Encoded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html). In a nutshell it escapes "unsafe" characters, which may not be safely included as is in URLs (and some other places). To reverse that you need to use [URLDecoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html).

As always when dealing with character conversions, you need to specify the encoding. UTF-8 is recommended, so unless you know you need something else, use that.